# Realtime update array from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to download information from a Firebase Firestore document that is then appended to an array in realtime. Everytime I add a document, delete or edit a document I would like the app to update and sync the array to match the data. I was able to retrieve the data with the following code:

```
database.collection("_Products").getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }else{
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                let Name = document.data()["Item Name"] as! String
                let Price = document.data()["Item Price"] as! String
                let Number = document.data()["Item Number"] as! String
                let Brand = document.data()["Item Brand"] as! String
                let Quantity = document.data()["Quantity"] as! String
                let Category = document.data()["Item Category"] as! String
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if instoreCheckOutArray.contains(where: {$0.Number == Number && $0.Brand == Brand}){
                        return
                    }else{
                        instoreCheckOutArray.append(checkOutArrayInfo(Brand: Brand, Name: Name, Number: Number, Price: Price, Quantity: Quantity, Category: Category))
                        self.searchForCoupon()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I then use the following code to run the function every second to fetch the data from the database:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCart), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Running the previous code perfectly fetches me new data but I cannot get the app to update the existing array to match the database and when I remove a document from the database it stays in the array.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why you need to fetch the data every second? You can use [listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) instead thats the reason we use `Firebase/Firestore` to avoid web service polling.

Comment: @TheTiger Thank you! That is exactly what I needed and somehow I was unaware of that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1.Declare scrollingTimer variable

```
var scrollingTimer = Timer()
```

2.Initialize scrollingTimer with your function

```
scrollingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCart), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

3.Fire the scrollingTimer(fire any where you want)

```
scrollingTimer.fire()
```

To stop the scrolling timer use the below line(Stop any where you want)

```
scrollingTimer.invalidate()
```

If any Please refer the  [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) (DevelopersDocument)